# Remember input values after submit - Best way?

Tags: php, jquery

After I've submitted multiple forms, I want to remember the values in the forms after the submit have been done.

The most spontaneous way I can think of is this:

```
<div class="top_child">
    <h3>Faktureringsuppgifter:</h3>
    <label name="firstname">Förnamn:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) { echo $_POST['firstname']; } ?>">
    <label name="lastname">Efternamn:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) { echo $_POST['lastname']; } ?>">
    <label name="personnmbr">Personnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="personnmbr">
    <label name="address">Gatuadress:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <label name="zip">Postnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip">
    <label name="city">Postort:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <label name="phone">Telefonnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone">
    <label name="customernmbr">Kundnummer</label>
    <input type="text" name="customernmbr">
</div>
```

I check every field with PHP? Is this a a nice way to do it?

>

Comment: Yes i think this is the only way, but i'm not very professional!

Comment: "Multiple forms" sounds like you could/should use `SESSIONS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use JS to do this, you can do the following;

```
var previousData = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
for (item in previousData) {
  // Check if item is set by you and not is a js property
  if (previousData.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    // Set the value to the input with same name
    $('input[name='+item+']').val(previousData[item]);
  }
}
```

Be aware that I use jQuery for this example.

http://jsbin.com/nadeb/7/edit?html,console,output

With this you don't need to add code in each input and don't need modify $_POST or create Sessions, etc.... So you need to do less changes and ever work. Only you can have problems if have input with names like this[is][an][field]. In this case maybe you'll need to do more elaborated javascript because $_POST store the field in an array this => is => an => field.

I'm not sure if it's the best practice but is easy to do and works hehe.

Comment: Thank. I liked this way to do it.

If I have multiple select boxes, how do I "remember" the options that I used after a submit?

Comment: Check this [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/nadeb/8/edit?html,console,output) `http://jsbin.com/nadeb/8/edit?html,console,output`

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer. But the options is not remembered after the submit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax method -> post and when you will be successful, nothing happens, so the form fields will be untouched.

e.g.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#button').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "example.php",
        data: "data="data,
        success: function(html){
            if(html=='true') {
                /* nothing */
            }
            else {
                                  /* nothing */
            }
        }
    });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sessions`

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['YOUR_KEY'] = 'YOUR_VALUE' // Probably $_POST['some_field_name'];
```

then access these values like so:

```
echo $_SESSION['YOUR_KEY'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input fields and pass the form data along the forms:

```
<?

    foreach($_POST as $name=>$value){

    ?><input type="hidden" name="<?=$name?>" value="<?=$value?>"><?

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert $_POST fields to HTML is bad solution.

First you need to validate and filter $_POST values: preg_match, htmlspecialchars and etc. And then copy cleared values into other array(as example $input_data).

In HTML you can just use:

```
<input name="lastname" value="<?=$input_data['lastname']?>" />
```

or

```
<input name="lastname" value="<?php echo $input_data['lastname']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For persistant data like this its best to use `$_SESSION`. When you submit your form assign the `$_POST` value to the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
```

Then in your HTML do

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['lastname'])) { echo $_SESSION['lastname']; } ?>">
```

Then after the form has been submitted and successfully passed validation you can unset the `$_SESSION` variables

```
unset($_SESSION['firstname']);
unset($_SESSION['lastname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jsp with a servlet for request and response you can do something like this in a html  tag.

```
<div class="top_child">
    <h3>Faktureringsuppgifter:</h3>
  <form>
    <label name="firstname">Förnamn:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value=${firstname}>
    <label name="lastname">Efternamn:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value=${lastname}>
    <label name="personnmbr">Personnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="personnmbr" value=${personnmbr}>
    <label name="address">Gatuadress:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" value=${address}>
    <label name="zip">Postnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" value=${zip}>
    <label name="city">Postort:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" value=${city}>
    <label name="phone">Telefonnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value=${phone}>
    <label name="customernmbr">Kundnummer</label>
    <input type="text" name="customernmbr" value=${customernmbr}>
    <input type="submit" value="submit>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `error_reporting` is not set to print notices, `$_POST['some_data']` will be empty, so just:

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?>">
```

will do, otherwise your solution is good.